# How use Mapbox Android SDK without Internet and/or without Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox

I've been following for a while now the development of the Android Mapbox SDK, knowing how great it looks on iOS. Now, we finally have a stable version we can use. My problem is this: I do not have access to the Internet often enough to use Gradle and havent been able to configure IDEA or Studio to work with Gradle completely offline.

Apparently, my only option to use the SDK is hardcoding the libraries into my project, but once again, i need to include the .aar file which requires Gradle.

I really wish to start tinkering with look like a great SDK, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you would want to follow the [building from source instructions](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk#building-from-source). You'll still need to run your computer with an internet connection initially to grab the files, but after that it'll be fine building offline.